# Linker Command Failed - C++ on OSX

Tags: c++, g++, clang, hdf5

I'm using HDF5 for C++ on mac. I'm compiling my code with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`. Clang is reporting the following error: `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`, with additional info above it being `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`.

One of the symbol errors are as follows:

`"readH5(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from: setupData(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int) in test-9aa0e6.o`

Would I be right in thinking there's a 32bit / 64bit dispute with the h5 library?

I'm a computer scientist, but I'm no C++ expert by any stretch, so if answers could be written for C++ beginners I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: What is `readH5`? Where is it defined (implemented)? Are you missing to link with a library?

Comment: Hi @Someprogrammerdude - readH5 is in a separate cpp file, which is definitely linked correctly, but also uses H5 properties. I used the readH5 error to highlight the symbol errors coming from H5 libraries in particular, not to highlight the specific function. Apologies for not being clear.

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp` builds the `test.cpp` source file and *only* that source file. Including a header file is not the same thing as building with other source files or linking with other object files or libraries.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by improper linking at build time.

The linking library needs to be specified.

With a library, we have to tell the compiler where the header files are and then tell the linker where the libraries are located with -l.

Can you try clang++ once?

You should also try:

`g++ test.cpp -o test -lhdf5 -I /usr/local/include`

`g++ test.cpp -o test -lhdf5 -I <hdf5 lib location>`

Comment: `-lhdf5 -I <hdf5 lib location>` should be `-L <hdf5 lib location> -lhdf5`. `-I` is for header files and OP doesn't have problems with the header files.

Comment: Hi @Vishnu. First, I tried your g++ command as is, error is `*** C++11 compiler required; enable C++11 mode in your compiler, or use an earlier version of Armadillo`. I then tried with the standard C++11 compiler flag, and my original error occurs. I didn't try the next suggestion as the hdf5 lib location is in the standard aforementioned directory. `clang++` instead of `g++` has the exact same results. @Ted Lyngmo, I tried the modified command as you suggested but it did not change the outcome. Thank you both for your support, but sadly the issue remains.

Comment: @DrKenReid Have you tried CMake yet? The official docs of HDF group suggest to use CMake on UNIX Platforms . `https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/knowledge/How+do+I+build+HDF5+from+source`.

Comment: @DrKenReid What does `ls -l <hdf5 lib location>/libhdf5*` show? Can you add the output from that command to your question?